# Nvidia Card Overheating

Tags: drivers, nvidia, overheating, nvidia-settings

So I've been trying really hard to get a stable linux install going, and my Nvidia graphics card has had other ideas...

I've successfully installed the drivers, Nvidia-361 is running right now, but the card runs way hotter than it should when no programs of any significance are running, around 60 C. Granted, this isn't really overheating, but something like 45-50 C is much more reasonable. I've tried to set up a maximum frequency using

```
nvidia-settings -a GPUOverclockingState=1
nvidia-settings -a GPU3DClockFreqs=400,800
```

but when I do this it says both of these are depricated. Is there anyway I can force throttle the graphics card or make it run cooler?

Running:
Kubuntu 16.04
MSI GS-70 Stealth Pro
Nvidia GTX 970M

Answer (score 0):

I had overheating problems with nvidia-361 drivers. 
In my case temperatures on gpu were about 80C peak and cpu 91C peak.

I have downgraded drivers to nvidia-340 through Additional drivers.

Now I have max 71C for gpu and max 75C for cpu.